# Javascript date comparison ignoring timestamp value

Tags: javascript, html

What is the simplest way to compare two dates neglecting the timestamps. I have got two dates `firstDate` coming from the database (converted into javascript date) and `secondDate` coming from a date picker input field. 
 Essentially for
my algorithm these two dates are equal as it doesn't take timestamp into consideration but the code won't consider it equal as `firstDate` has `01:00:00` in it. 
How to completely discard the timestamp for comparison?

**firstDate:**

> Tue Mar 24 1992 01:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

**secondDate:**

> Tue Mar 24 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

**Code:**

```
   if(firstDate < secondDate) {

        alert("This alert shouldn't pop out as dates are equal");
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `toDateString` to get rid of the the time, and reassign that to the firstDate and secondDate variables. There might be a better way, but this is what came to mind for me.

```
firstDate = new Date(firstDate.toDateString());
secondDate = new Date(secondDate.toDateString());
if(firstDate < secondDate){
    alert("This alert shouldn't pop out as dates are equal");
}
```

Also, you'll want to make sure you're comparing the values of the dates, and not checking if they're the same object when you compare if they're equal. So something like.

```
firstDate.valueOf() == secondDate.valueOf()
```

You can also check out my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/Kt5CZ/).

Comment: Derek thanks for the reply. I had the same solution wondering if there is another way. If no body else replied I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Date.setHours(hrs, mins, secs, ms)` function with all zero arguments to set the time of day to midnight in both dates (make a copy if you need the date with the time for other purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Derek's answer is correct.  An alternative method without creating new date instances is to create RFC3339 date strings.

```
var firstDateStr = firstDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
var secondDateStr = secondDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

return (firstDateStr < secondDateStr);
```

Comment: In my example, I'm not comparing strings, but rather `new Date()` initialized with the result from the `toDateString()`